# Somewhat inconsistent need for template disambiguator

Tags: c++, templates, c++23

In the example below, I need to use the `template` disambiguator in the line marked as #1, while it appears to be unnecessary in the other occurrence of a similar pattern. What does it make the difference?

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

template<std::size_t n, typename TFn>
constexpr void constexpr_for(TFn Fn)
{
  [&Fn]<std::size_t... i>(std::index_sequence<i...>)
    { (Fn(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, i>{}), ...); } (std::make_index_sequence<n>{});
}

struct TVertex {};

class TFace
{
public:
  static constexpr std::size_t NVertex = 3u;

private:
  std::array<TVertex const *, NVertex> VertexVec;

public:
  template<std::size_t i>
  TVertex const &GetVertex() const
    { return *std::get<i>(VertexVec); }
};

void f(std::vector<TFace> const &FaceVec)
{
  for (auto const &[i, Face1] : std::views::zip(std::views::iota(0u), FaceVec))
    constexpr_for<TFace::NVertex>([&](auto const j)
      {
      for (auto const &[_, Face2] : std::views::zip(std::views::iota(0u), FaceVec)
                                  | std::views::drop(i + 1u))
        constexpr_for<TFace::NVertex>([&](auto const k)
          {
            TVertex const &Vertex1 = Face1.GetVertex<j>();
            TVertex const &Vertex2 = Face2.template GetVertex<k>(); // #1
          });
      });
}
```

I’m using GCC trunk. Here’s a Compiler Explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/Kh6n6G4hW

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. With emphasis on __minimal__.

Comment: @PasserBy That's the most minimal example I could came up with by reduction from my codebase. Should I remove `f2` as it is only an example of other situations in which `template` isn't needed?

Comment: You don't need `[[maybe_unused]]`, range adapters, vectors and arrays to demonstrate a syntax question, except in the rare case that you found a supremely intricate compiler bug.

Comment: @PasserBy I couldn't reproduce without using `views::zip`. I added `[[maybe_unused]]` to silence unrelated warnings.

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/z/EMTTh1rMo) is minimal. What you have is not.

Comment: @PasserBy Sorry. I thought my example was sufficiently concise to show clearly what my problem was. Yours is clearly better as you were able to avoid the nested loops, which I couldn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal way to reproduce your error:

```cpp
#include <utility>

class TFace
{
public:
  template<int i>
  void GetVertex() const {}
};

template<typename>
void f1()
{
    auto const &[_, Face2] = std::pair<int, TFace>{};
    Face2.GetVertex<0>(); // #1
}
```

Since this compiles on clang, I'm thinking that this is a GCC bug. GCC seems to think that `Face2` is a dependent name, even though it clearly isn't (The types of all the variables in:

```cpp
  std::views::zip(std::views::iota(0u), FaceVec)
| std::views::drop(i + 1u)
```

are not dependent on any template argument).

This bug does have a simple workaround fortunately, adding `Face2.template GetVertex` as you have. It might look better or be less confusing if you wrote `Face1.template GetVertex` as well.

---

My hypothesis is that in the structured binding, `Face2` is initialized similarly to `get<1>(*zip_iterator)` with ADL, and GCC incorrectly assumes that this is dependent (even though `zip_iterator` is not dependent).

The reason `Face1` works without `.template` is that it is defined in `f` which is not a template, so it cannot possibly be dependent. `Face2` is templated, since it is in a generic lambda, even if it doesn't end up being dependent.

Comment: It was indeed a GCC bug, which has just been fixed by this patch: https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2022-November/607476.html Thanks!